# colorspace won't change colors in beamer

Tags: pdftex, color

So I'm trying to do a spotcolor define in a beamer document and for some reason I'm getting a problem. Whenever I try and do more than one color, only one color shows up. For example the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\RequirePackage{colorspace}

\definespotcolor{foo}{BarTone 555 GN}{.8,.2,.5,.3}
\definespotcolor{boo}{Random}{.8,.5,.2,.3}

\begin{document}
  \color{foo}Green
  \color{boo}Blue
\end{document}
```

When I do this, both "Blue" and "Green" show up as green. I even tried putting braces around them: `{\color{foo}Green}` but that didn't stop the problem from occuring. Any thoughts on this?

Here's some system info:

```
xxx:~ $ tlmgr info colorspace
package:     colorspace
category:    Package
shortdesc:   Provides PDF color spaces
longdesc:    The package provides PDF color spaces. Currently, only spot colors and overprinting     are supported. It requires xcolor, and supports pdfTeX and LuaTeX.
installed:   Yes
revision:    50585
sizes:       doc: 141k, run: 25k
relocatable: No
cat-version: 1.3
cat-license: mit
cat-topics:  colour
cat-contact-home: http://www.texnia.com/
cat-contact-repository: https://github.com/jbezos/colorspace
collection:  collection-latexextra

xxx:~ $ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a colorspace bug. It defines a command globally and with beamer (which handles color differently than with xcolor alone) this breaks.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\RequirePackage{colorspace}

\definespotcolor{foo}{BarTone 555 GN}{.8,.2,.5,.3}
\definespotcolor{boo}{Random}{.8,.5,.2,.3}

\makeatletter
\def\spc@getref#1 #2\@@{\def\spc@ir{#1}} %changed \gdef to def
\makeatother


\begin{document}
  \color{foo}Green
  \color{boo}Blue 
\end{document}
```

Comment: This kind of works, but then throws problems with tikz ._. Is there a way to make it work with tikz as well? Example of something that fails: `\begin{tikzpicture}[gr/.style={color=foo}] \draw[gr] (0,0) -- (1,0); \end{tikzpicture}` (This is kind of a different issue now, so if you want I can create another question so that I can accept this one, since this does *technically* fix the above problem.

Comment: well it could be that my fix is wrong (the colorspace code isn't the easiest and it has to go through some loops to hook into xcolor), but better make another question anyway with an example.

Comment: It looks like it's a different issue anyway, so that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Here's a link to the new question if you want to check it out: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552508/colorspace-with-beamer-and-tikz-having-issues