# colorspace with beamer and tikz having issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, color, colorspace

This is a follow-up to [colorspace won't change colors in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552478/colorspace-wont-change-colors-in-beamer) where I'm getting issues with the `colorspace` package in beamer. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\RequirePackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{colorspace}

\definespotcolor{foo}{BarTone 555 GN}{.8,.2,.5,.3}

% Problem exists even without fix
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552478/colorspace-wont-change-colors-in-beamer
%\makeatletter
%\def\spc@getref#1 #2\@@{\def\spc@ir{#1}} %changed \gdef to def
%\makeatother                                                                                                                                                                                                     

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gr/.style={color=foo}]
    \draw[gr] (0,0) -- (10,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get the following error (I'm only showing the part that seems to have info):

```
Runaway argument?
picture bounding box\endcsname {rectangle} \expandafter \edef \csname \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \spc@getref.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> tmp.tex
       
! Emergency stop.
<*> tmp.tex
```

I can't figure out what is happening. If I change `foo` to `green` for example, there is no error being generated. So it's only when I use a spotcolor that there is a problem.

I'm using the 2020 version of texlive and the latest 1.3 version of colorspace. Any thoughts?

Comment: well it is not my fix, it fails without it too. but beside this it is quite a mess ;-(.

Comment: Yeah, I should remove your fix because it still causes the same problem without it ._. It seems like a mess for some reason. The weird part is that it used to work in 2018. So something changed in the last couple years that made it stop working =/

Comment: It doesn't work in texlive 2018 for me. I get the error mentioned here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/385570/2388. And with article it doesn't error but it doesn't give the correct color either.

Comment: Maybe it was 2017? I do know that it used to work because I've made beamer presentations with the above and it had no errors. I did it in March 2018. Also, you'd need to make sure to use the older version of colorspace ._.

Comment: It errors in 2017 and 2016 too. Also even if it not errorred, did it actually used spot colors? And why are you using spot colors for a presentation?

Comment: Weird.. I wonder why it used to work. Maybe I just never noticed the errors? ._. I'm using them because from what I understand, pantone colors are best done using spot colors. So mainly for conformity purposes.

Comment: If you don't print the document spot color are useless. The pdf viewer will use the rgb/cmyk fallback.

Comment: Yeah, it's a poster (hence the package beamerposter) so it should be printed. If it was just going to be a normal pdf file then I wouldn't care as much. (Although since it's not working it's not like I'll have much options anyway)